# How can I align colon characters and text?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to align the colons and text in such style that the colons would be the same line as the next row of colons, and also with the text.
First picture is desired result, second picture is current result.

[image: Desired Result]

[image: Current Progress]

However, as you can see in my current progress the alignment is off a bit, where the column and right text is not at the same 'height' as the left text.

Below is my code:

```html
<span style='width: 100px;clear: left;float: left;text-align: left;padding-right: 2px;'>PolicyNo</span>: XXX<br/>

<span style='width: 100px;clear: left;float: left;text-align: left;padding-right: 2px;'>PolicyNo RRRR</span>: YYY<br/>
```

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: what font style are you using?

Comment: You can't apply width to inline elements such as spans.

Comment: All that forced layout isn't easy to create or maintain, and your styles should be applied to classes in an embedded style tag, not on the elements. Look at [CSS grid](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/) for a modern approach to this type of thing.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to align labels on a div layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47128995/how-to-align-labels-on-a-div-layout)

Comment: @Saravanan font face='verdana', size='1'

Comment: Note that those attributes are deprecated (not valid in HTML5). Be sure you're following modern standards. Floats are also largely archaic. [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/) is an excellent resource.

Answer (score 0):

After a bit of testing I found that this works:

```
<span style='width: 100px; padding-right: 0; margin-right:0;'>PolicyNo </span>: XXX<br/>

<span style='width: 100px; padding-right: 0; margin-right:0;'>PolicyNo </span>: YYY<br/>
```

Answer (score 0):

The only way I was able to center the semicolon was using the pseudo-element which is a roundabout the real problem.

move up the semicolon after adding it using `content`.

I'm not really sure why this happened to you. but I think it's something related to the fonts

```css
.semi {
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 4px;
}

.semi::before {
  position: absolute;
  content: ":";
  left: -18px;
  top: -8%;
  height: 100%;
}

div {
  font-size: 62px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span style='width: 300px;clear: left;float: left;text-align: left;padding-right: 2px;'>PolicyNo</span>
  <span class="semi"> XXX</span> <br />
</div>
```

NOTE that if you change the `font-size` you may need to readjust the `top` value. Give it a shot and let me know if that worked for you.